# Error while streaming video file from server to client with gstreamer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I'm trying to transmit video and play it on the client PC. 
The pipeline (server side):

```
 gst-launch videotestsrc ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.16 port=5000
```

works fine.
But now, I need to transfer a video file and not videotestsrc from the server. This is the pipeline:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=movie.mp4 ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.16 port=5000
```

and I get this error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

** (gst-launch-0.10:10550): CRITICAL **: gst_ffmpegenc_chain_video: assertion `frame_size == GST_BUFFER_SIZE (inbuf)' failed
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2625): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

It seems like the buffer has not enough space (I think...).

Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: You're opening a mp4 file and trying to encode it to mpeg4? Either just send the original file or decode it before reencoding (e.g. using `decodebin`)

Comment: I also tried to send yuv with very small resolution (qcif) and I got the same error...

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look at your second pipeline:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=movie.mp4 ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.16 port=5000
```

You're connecting `filesrc` (which is in your case reading an encoded `.mp4` file and outputting the raw contents of the file without knowing anything about its format).

Then you're stuffing that data directly to `ffenc_mpeg4`.
Looking at the sink caps using `gst-inspect ffenc_mpeg4` we get the following information:

```
…
Pad Templates:
  …
  SINK template: 'sink'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-raw-rgb
      video/x-raw-yuv
      video/x-raw-gray
…
```

So `ffenc_mpeg4` expects raw *unencoded* video at its sink (=input), but what it gets is mpeg4 data (which isn't declared as such).

So there are two possible solutions to our problem:

- Send the mp4 file unmodified. That way the server has to do nothing but reading a file and writing its contents to a network socket.

  ```
  gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=movie.mp4 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.16 port=5000
  ```

  That way the server doesn't have to do any cpu-intensive re-encoding and therefore should need very few resources.
  But if you've got source files in different formats, the clients will have to support all of them (and detect them correctly).
- The other way is to decode the file before re-encoding it again (by simply adding a `decodebin` to your pipeline):

  ```
  gst-launch filesrc location=movie.mp4 ! decodebin ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.16 port=5000
  ```

  Here the advantage is that (when configuring the encoder elements accordingly) no matter which input file format you get, as long as your server can decode it, you'll end up with a MPEG4 UDP stream, but the server might waste resources (and lose video quality) by decoding a file just to encode it back into the same format.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I have another question- im monitorring the output with wireshark and i see udp packets instead of rtp packets (at the end of thr pipeline there is rtpmp4vpay.  How can I send the data via rtp?

Comment: Well as far as I know `udpsink` sends pretty much raw data. If you want RTSP, you'll need another sink element. You might wanna have a look at http://weeklybuild.com/2013/01/creating-an-rtsp-stream-with-gstreamer/